# Prevent Cloud Run from passing on Authorization header

Tags: go, google-cloud-run

I have Grafana hosted on Cloud Run. Grafana has anonymous access enabled while Cloud Run needs valid credentials.

Now I try mimic the first example of https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/dashboard/. Thus I downloaded a service account key to `/tmp/creds.json`. This file I set as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.
Using these credentials I then send a POST to `/api/dashboards/db`.
What I see is that I get through Google auth, it starts up Cloud Run instances and I get an error message from Grafana:

```
{"message":"invalid API key"}
```

This in turn then lets me believe that Google auth is not consuming the `Authorization` header but delegating it along.

So my question is how can I prevent Google auth from delegate this header?
Or as a workaround how can I make Grafana ignore the header?

Here the source I use to make the requests:

```golang
func TestCall(t *testing.T) {
    r := strings.NewReader(`
    {
      "dashboard": {
        "id": null,
        "uid": null,
        "title": "Production Overview",
        "tags": [ "templated" ],
        "timezone": "browser",
        "schemaVersion": 16,
        "version": 0,
        "refresh": "25s"
      },
      "folderId": 0,
      "folderUid": "l3KqBxCMz",
      "message": "Made changes to xyz",
      "overwrite": false
    }
    `)
    os.Setenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "/tmp/creds.json")
    ctx := context.TODO()
    ts, err := idtoken.NewTokenSource(ctx, "https://grafana-123.run.app")
    if err != nil {
        if !strings.HasPrefix(err.Error(), "idtoken: credential must be service_account") {
            panic(err)
        }
        creds, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        ts = creds.TokenSource
    }
    tok, err := ts.Token()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if tok.AccessToken == "" {
        panic("Empty token!")
    }
    fmt.Printf("AT %s\n", tok.AccessToken)
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://grafana-123.run.app/api/dashboards/db", r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+tok.AccessToken)
    // This does not work at all: req.Header.Set("Proxy-Authorization", "Bearer "+tok.AccessToken)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode < 200 || resp.StatusCode >= 300 {
        fmt.Printf("SC %d\n", resp.StatusCode)
        bs, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        panic(string(bs))
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you could set up oidc based access  in grafana, with google as the identity provider, and then the user's identity would be exposed to grafana.  https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/google/

Comment: My experience with OIDC and multiple layers of authentication/reverse proxies/load balancers is that you need to be VERY knowledgeable about every last piece to make it work. And I am not ;)

Answer (score 1):

The header Proxy-Authorization should work, but I have also been unsuccessful.

To clarify your problem, you are using IAP (OIDC Identity Token) to authorize access to Cloud Run. Your software (Grafana) is processing the HTTP Authorization header and assuming that you are passing it an API Key (which fails). I am not familiar with Grafana internals, but one possible solution is to write middleware that detects an OIDC token and removes that header. I am not aware of a Cloud Run method to remove the Authorization header from HTTP requests that your application receives.

IMHO this is a problem that should be resolved in Grafana's code. If Grafana has anonymous access enabled, then it should not be validating the HTTP Authorization header. Consider opening an issue with Grafana or fixing the code and submitting a patch.

Comment: I try not to use IAP on purpose (AFAIK you cannot use ADC with IAP). Whatever networking instances are sitting in front of Google Cloud instances - AFAIK they only validate the `Authorization` header.

Comment: @abergmeier - If you mean ADC as in Application Default Credentials, yes, you can use that method with IAP. ADC is not a credential, ADC is a method of finding credentials.

Comment: What I mean with ADC is the credentials that are available by e.g. gcloud. And since IAP seems to force you to use a custom OAuth client id, I think the "gcloud adc" can not be used with IAP since the scopes are different.

Comment: Yes, you can use the CLI (gcloud). However, it depends on the type of identity that the CLI is authorized with.